# Difference between Liferay Mobile SDK and Liferay Screens

Tags: mobile, liferay, liferay-6

Can someone tell me the difference between `Liferay Mobile SDK` and `Liferay Screens`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the respective homepages of the products, first hits on google on the product names (bold by me):

[Liferay Mobile SDK](https://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-mobile-sdk/overview) is a framework for building native mobile apps that integrate with your different Liferay Portal instances and their portlets. The SDK provides the means for your mobile apps to easily **consume Liferay Portal's core web services** and the web services of your custom portlets. It **wraps Liferay JSON web services**, takes care of authentication, makes HTTP requests (synchronously or asynchronously), parses JSON results and handles server side exceptions.

[Liferay Screens](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/liferay-projects/liferay-screens) is a collection of **fully native mobile components**, ...

Thus, with the Mobile SDK you have components to call services on Liferay Portal (and your plugins). Liferay Screens provides you with building blocks that allow you to build the full frontend of your application built with a Liferay backend.

With Mobile SDK you'll have to build the UI yourself, but it's easy to embed Liferay's data.

More details than these on the linked homepages

Answer (score 0):

Liferay SDK is a Mobile Native API and includes a Native API generator to invoce services (Portal and Custom Plugin remote services as well) while Liferay Screens are native, reusable, themable and extensible visual components that are based on Mobile SDK as well.
Here there are available diagrams for Liferay Screens (for IOS and Android) respectively:

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/architecture-of-liferay-screens-for-ios

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/architecture-of-liferay-screens-for-android